# 3D object with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]
I would like to draw this object with F facing down.
Unfortunately I am not very good at TikZ, especially with 3D objects.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you provide the code of what you have so far?

Comment: Do you mean that F is the colored báe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose a 3D-like way of drawing with TikZ. Just draw as it looks like ^^. And next time try to post a minimal working example to show what you have tried.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\shiftpoint{(.8,-1)}
\path
(0,0) coordinate (A1) +\shiftpoint coordinate (B1)
(2.7,3)  coordinate (A2) +\shiftpoint coordinate (B2)
(A1-|A2) coordinate (A3) +\shiftpoint coordinate (B3)
;
\draw[dashed] (A1)--(A3) (A2)--(A3);
\draw (A1) parabola (A2);
\draw[fill=blue!50] (B1) parabola (B2)--(B3)--cycle;
\path (B3) node[above left=4mm]{$F$};
\draw (A1)--(B1) (A2)--(B2);
\foreach \p in {A1,A2,B1,B2,B3}
\draw[fill=white] (\p) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```